# Why auto specifier deduce "top and low" level const from an &pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, visual-c++, auto

My code is

```
    const int *const ptrA = nullptr;
    auto *ptrB = &ptrA;
```

My percepcion from `const int *const ptrA` is:

- (`*const`) is "top-level const"
- (`const int`) is "low-level const"

So, ptrB must be `const int**` type.

My question is...

> Why `ptrB` is not `const int**` type if "top-level const" are ignored?

Comment: The crux is that `ptrB` has top, middle and low (three levels) where `const` could be present.

Comment: @MicroVirus What would be each const leve?

Answer (score 1):

`ptrB` is of type `const int* const*`.

`ptrA` itself is const, points to const int. You get its address, thus `ptrB` points to const pointer to const int.

Answer (score 0):

Top-level `const` is indeed ignore in template argument deduction (as is `volatile`), but you *don't* have any top-level const qualifier!

You have `&ptrA` which is a pointer to `const int *const`, so a `const int *const*`. There is no top-level `const` anymore. Which is why `ptrB` is of type `const int *const*`.

If you had `auto ptrB = ptrA`; then yes, the top-level `const` will get ignored.

Answer (score 0):

So for `auto *ptrB = ptrA;`, your perception would be correct (resulting in `auto` = `const int*` whereas `ptrA` is `const int* const`),

but type of `&ptrA` is `const int *const*`, no `const` to drop.

Answer (score 0):

> Why `ptrB` is not `const int**` type if "top-level const" are ignored?

It would be ignored if you use:

```
auto *ptrB = ptrA;
```

Then, `ptrB` will be of type `const int*`.

However, the top level `const` is not ignored when you use the address of operator.

Regarding

> So, `ptrB` must be `const int**` type.

No, it is of type `const int* const*`. It will easier to read if the type is stated as `int const* const*`. `ptrB` is a pointer to a `const` pointer to a `const int`.